# VS Code - Can't associate .ts file with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I create a .ts file in a project, VS Code interprets it as "plain text". When I try to "Configure File Association for .ts", there are a few dozen languages to choose from but TypeScript is not one of them. Adding the following in settings.json doesn't seem to do anything:

`"files.associations": { ".ts": "typescript" }`

I have disabled extensions and commented out everything else in settings.json. I must be missing something obvious.

Note: fixed the issue by completely uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code.

Comment: VS Code comes with TypeScript built-in. I'd reinstall VS Code at this point...

Comment: Reinstalling fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that the built-in "TypeScript Language Basics" extension is enabled.

This solved the problem for me.  I had disabled it in a misguided attempt to get Volar's takeover mode working.  For Volar takeover mode, you only should disable the "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" extension.

Comment: This can be found by searching `@builtin typescript` within the Extensions panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in the visual code terminal

npm install -g typescript

Comment: I should have mentioned that typescript is already installed globally. So that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I might be off-base, but does `"files.associations": { "*.ts": "typescript" }` help? Note the asterisk.