# Visual Studio Code does not regognize typescript files (*.ts and *.tx)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I installed typescript via `npm install -g typescript`

`tcs --version` returns `4.1.3`

But when I open a folder which contains `.ts` and `.tx` files those files are displayed as plain text.

When I click on the plain text in the bottom bar to select an associated language typescript is not an option I can select.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try restarting your computer, in case it's something to do with environment variables. Is there an extension you have to install to get typescript as an option?

Comment: I restarted my computer, and I disabled all extensions one by one. No success

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, I am not sure what else will work.

Comment: so when I completely remove vscode and install a fresh version it works. But as soon as I turn on sync to get my old settings and extension back the problem comes back again...

Comment: [Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775452/vs-code-cant-associate-ts-file-with-typescript)